# IIS cannot serve a PDF file when containing folder has serveral files

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

This is very strange. I developed an ASP.NET web site that in some part of the code, it validates if a file exists, by mean of the following method:

```
File.Exists(Server.MapPath(archivo))
```

That method returns false even when the file exists.

When I point the browser directly to the PDF, I got a 403 forbidden error.

Containing folder has about 81,000 files.

If I copy that PDF file to other directory, where that file is the only file there, I can point the browser there and the PDF is shown.

What may be happening here?

EDIT:

Added Hidden Segments screenshot:

[image]

Thanks
Jaime

Comment: Does the name of the directory with the PDFs in happen to be the same as a hidden segment in IIS? To see: in IIS Manager, select the site, in the "IIS" section open "Request Filtering", then choose the "Hidden Segments" tab. To solve: give the directory a different name.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I have added Hidden Segments tab screenshot to the question. The PDF folder is not listed there.

Comment: You need to examine the IIS logs and determine what kind of 403 you are experiencing.  c:\inetpub\logs\Logfiles.

Comment: And to go along with Rich-Langs comment: [The HTTP status code in IIS 7 and later versions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0).

Comment: I have seen log files and no error was shown.. and in fact, status code was 200 when I tried to view the PDF in the browser. I have enable the display of full error in IIS by setting httpErrors errorMode and that way, browser sends a 401.3 error. Other fact I have not told you is that this is a virtual directory, that was pointed to another disk in the server. However, I have created, at the same level, another virtual directory and that has no problems.

Comment: If you are getting 403 forbidden and not finding them in the IIS logs, then you need to be examining other appliances between your client and IIS Server.  WRT to 401.3, that is a very specific error indicating Unauthorized due to ACL on resource.  Examine the ACLs on the file in this Virtual Directory and ensure the correct users have Read permissions.  This will include either the Anonymous User account (default = IUSR) or logged in user if using WindowsAuth.  Compare permissions between your two working folders.

Comment: In case of a web application that runs under an application pool, the user is IUSR too?